# Solve single complex equation on TI-84 Plus C Silver Edition

Tags: calculator

I found .8xp files that I can download onto my calculator to solve a system of complex equations, but it is useless when I'm just trying to solve one equation. The solve feature on the calculator only works with non-complex numbers, so that is useless to me as well. I would like to know if there are any files out there that I can download so I can solve a single complex equation on the TI-84 Plus C Silver Edition calculator. I've searched for about 2 hours now and I haven't found anything.

Note: I have been using Wolfram Alpha for this, but I can't use that on exams, so that's why I need it specifically for this calculator.